# Do Azure Data Factory updates the functions and formulae in Excel file while fetching?

Tags: excel, azure, azure-data-factory

I have been working on a dynamic Excel file using Azure Data Factory to move data from Excel file to Azure SQL.

The context is:
My test Excel file is having only one cell filled with data with `NOW()` function.

In excel, every time I refresh the file the `NOW()` function I get the latest date and time.
But when, I preview the data in ADF, I get the old date and time every time (Not latest)

Now the question is:

Can I refresh the Excel file using ADF OR ADF can only make use of static Excel file. If there is a way to use dynamic Excel file in ADF, kindly let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, it will read the values in the Excel file, and not update cells in them. The Excel xlsx file format is basically a zipped xml document. Each cell will have the formula and value stored in it.

```
<sheetData>
    <row r="1" spans="1:1" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25">
        <c r="A1" s="1">
            <f ca="1">NOW()</f>
            <v>44866.627317708335</v>
        </c>
    </row>
</sheetData>
```

In the above example cell A1 has the formula of NOW()

NOW()

And a value of

44866.627317708335

which is the float value of the date when it was refreshed.

You can't use ADF to refresh the file. You would have to use a logic app or [power automate to load the Excel](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/refresh-excel-every-morning/td-p/1272791), to open, refresh and save it. Which you can call in your ADF pipeline. However, it will be limited to Excel Online.